# no response to setVisibility

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an app with buttons that trigger sound and want the buttons to be only visible when pressed I add the setVisibility method but when I press the button there is no response.

My code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout background;
ImageButton btn;
MediaPlayer sound;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sound.release();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kick);
                btn.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mp.start();

        }
    });




}

}
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:background="@drawable/fuckyou"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/oneeee"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />
```

Logcat shows following:

```
06-20 02:02:57.249  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 I/art﹕ Not late-   enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-20 02:02:57.249  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
06-20 02:02:57.251  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
06-20 02:02:57.673  28473-28484/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8726(388KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 10MB/10MB, paused 6.293ms total 56.655ms
06-20 02:02:57.695  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
06-20 02:02:57.710  28473-28489/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-20 02:02:57.714  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab1704a0, tid 28473
06-20 02:02:57.728  28473-28473/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
06-20 02:02:57.775  28473-28489/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab170540, tid 28489
06-20 02:02:57.804  28473-28489/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-20 02:02:57.857  28473-28489/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-20 02:02:57.857  28473-28489/sp.umavibe.com.sp404 W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab163c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Try refreshing parent layout,in which the button resides.
Relativelayout.requestLayout().

Answer (score 0):

Try -     `v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

You are making INVISIBLE button then how it is going to get click event. you have to make it visible to perform click event.
code -

```
 btn.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.kick);
                mp.start();

        }
});
```

and add following line in layout-

```
  android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: now the button just appears without using the method :(

Comment: sorry meant to say there's still no response after adding the android:clickable="true"

Comment: is given xml is activity_main.xml?

Comment: let me know 1 thing you are setting btn1 invisible at first time then how you able to click on that? Try my updated code.

Comment: down-vote for posting wall of code without explanation

Comment: ur code worked, but when i try to set the button to be visible only when pressed it doesn't work